# Can we add a "follow question" option?

Tags: feature-request

I don't like when one day I am contemplating answering a question, but then I reach my question limit or I want time to think about it, and forget to favourite the question. Then I go back the next day and I don't find the question! I am sure many other Stack Exchange users would appreciate a "follow question" option. It would be nice if we could "monitor" our favourited questions from our inbox, eg. "So and so has added a new answer on your favourited question" or "You favourited a question 1 minute ago". Or, it could be included next to the "Recent achievements" section in the top left-hand corner, making it easier to access, instead of looking through our profile. Can we make this happen?

Comment: Could you explain why the "Favourite" functionality doesn't do what you want? It allows you to find the question more easily -- what other benefit are you looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any of your favorite (starred) questions which has had recent activity will be highlighted in yellow on the "favorites" tab of your profile page.

Comment: Like much SE functionality beyond the basics, the favourites tab is so hidden as to be useless to most people.

Comment: @AndyT The favorites tab is right there on the primary profile page (`http://english.stackexchange.com/users/nnn`). It's not hidden, though the page is pretty dense which makes *everything* on it a bit obscure.