# Could we add a feature that tracks visited questions in the "all actions" tab?

Tags: feature-request

This is similar to my other question:

> [Can we add a "follow question" option?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9732/can-we-add-a-follow-question-option?noredirect=1#comment38317_9732)

Except what if you don't want to favourite, or potentially "follow" the question initially, but wish to find it later? It would be nice if there was a "history" or "recently viewed" section next to or inside the "all actions" tab. Could we make this happen?

Comment: Because all SE sites in the network share the same features, this feature request would be implemented network-wide. So it is not really an [english.se] request and would be better proposed on the network-wide meta site: http://meta.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two questions you asked on English Language and Usage SE Meta should be asked on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) as it will affect all SE sites. You can't have this feature change just for ELU SE.

In the meantime, if you find a question interesting and you'd like to follow it, you can just *favorite* it and you will be able to find it under the tab "favorites" under Activity in your user profile.

Related FAQ on Meta SE: [How do favorite questions work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work)